# Is Javascript closures and Swift closures are same

Tags: javascript, swift, closures

Are Javascript closures and First class functions and Swift closures and first-class functions are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, yes.

The base difference is that in Swift closure is a reference type. So, you have to be aware of using strong references for income captured variables.

Comment: the same is true in JavaScript; it's just that Apple platforms use reference counting, whereas JavaScript implementations use a tracing garbage collector, so don't have issues with reference cycles